# Creating a varbinary column in a mysql database using code first Entity framework 4.1

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework-4, varbinary

When I try to create a varbinary column "Data" using the entity framework and a code first method by defining data as.

```
Public Property Data() As Byte()
```

The problem is that when I run the program the script generated for this table doesnt specify a length for varbinary, which obviously breaks the execution and returns syntax errors from the mysql server.

```
CREATE TABLE `TestAction`(
    `ID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    `Name` mediumtext NOT NULL, 
    `Data` varbinary, 
    `Tested` datetime NOT NULL, 
    `TestID` int NOT NULL);
```

I have already tried to initiate the byte array and added a max length attribute to the property but with no success. Has anyone succesfully done this? or can help it would be much appreciated

Answer----

Ive managed to solve this in the using the fluent api to force the entity framework to cast my byte() to varbinary and then setting the max length in the associated EntityTypeConfiguration class. I tried somthing similar before but conbined the length with the type name in the HasColumnType() method such that ...HasColumnType("varbinary(45) but that didnt work. The below line of code however solved my problem.

```
[Property](Function(P) P.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(45).HasColumnType("varbinary")
```